# Display first element of array without looping

Tags: angular

I have an array that i want to display from it the first item in a span .

At the moment i'm getting all the value instead of only the first one.

```html
<div class="card">  
  <div *ngIf="selectedUser._id">
    <div class="user" *ngFor="let user of users">
       <span> {{ user.event }} </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's returning me the list of all users date event, i only want the first one

I also tried to add user.event[0] not working it's displaying me the first char of the date

my array of object

```json
[
   {
      id:XYZ, 
      event: Fri Jul 20 2018 15:00:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)
   }, {
      id:XYZ1, 
      name: Fri Jul 10 2018 15:00:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)
   }, {
      id:XYZ2, 
      name: Fri Aug 20 2018 15:00:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)
   }
]
```

I tried this solution that is working and achieving what i want

```html
<div class="message" *ngFor="let user of users | slice:0:1;">
```

But I know this is looping through the array, I need to get the first element without doing it.

I already tried this :

```html
<span> {{ users[0].event }} </span>
```

it's throwing me an error cause sometimes the event is undefined

Comment: ```users[0]?.event```

Comment: chances are big that you want to make the entire `div` or `span` conditional to the existence of `users[0]`, which leads me to the conclusion that you want to centralize it in a method `firstUser`, see below.

Answer (score 3):

You should check if array item is empty or not

```html
<span> {{ users && users.length ? users[0].event : '' }} </span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [**safe navigation operator**](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) i.e. **`?`** to make sure the users array is checked for **`undefined`**.

> The Angular safe navigation operator (?.) is a more fluent and
>   convenient way to guard against nulls in property paths. The
>   expression bails out when it hits the first null value. The display is
>   blank, but the app keeps rolling without errors.

```
<span *ngIf="users[0]">
    {{ users[0]?.event }}
</span>
```

Link to [**StackBlitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tl6jmq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: the question remains, do you even want an empty `span` if there is no user. Perhaps you don't want to print the `span` all together in that case. Or perhaps you want to print `"no user found"`

Comment: @bvdb add an `*ngIf` then, see the updated answer and demo.

Comment: indeed, but then you don't need the `?` operator, right ?

Answer (score 2):

Just **try** this:

```
<span> {{ users[0]?.event }} </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution will be to write a method `firstUser()` in your Component class.

Your typescript file should contain

```
firstUser () {
  return this.users[0];
}
```

This just keeps your html section as clean as possible. Chances are big that you will need to use it twice anyway:

```
    <div class="user" *ngIf="firstUser" >
         <span>  {{ firstUser.event }} </span>
    </div>
```

You may even want to print a message like `"no user found"` instead.